# Сheck for duplicate photos on Apple devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mac, photos.app

Here's the thing, I have iPhone, iPad and Mac. On each device there is a bunch of photo copies. Is it possible to find and delete photos from my iOS devices that are on my Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try interPhotos app. It may work for you. But you have to download both versions for Mac and iOS